# Populate b.field into a.field when 2 vector points not always coincident but should be coincident

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, pgadmin-3, function, trigger

Using QGIS/pgAdmin3, I have a situation where two vector points, should be coincident but I can't guarantee they always are, I need to take feature a.field and populate a field in feature b, upon both insert and update to the geometry, update being let's say feature a has been moved spatially to be coincident to a new/different b feature.

A lot of my attempts have resulted in this error:

```
Could not commit changes to layer term

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

  Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
    CONTEXT:  SQL statement "update term set
    station_id = (select id from struct
    where
    st_within(term.geom, st_buffer(struct.geom, 0.1)))"
    PL/pgSQL function term_station_id_update() line 5 at SQL statement
```

I am trying to create the right function to use with insert and update triggers, function attempt is as follows:

```
update term set 

station_id = (select id from struct

where

st_within(term.geom, st_buffer(struct.geom, 0.1)));"
```

I have also tried similar functions with `st_dwithin`, `st_within`, and just with the geometry being = between the two layers if truly coincident, does not work however, similar error messages return.

Comment: when i try 

update term set
station_id = (select id from struct
where st_intersects(term.geom, struct.geom));

Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function term_station_id_update()

Comment: Trouble is that your term geometry is intersecting more than one geometry from struct and construction of query needs subquery to return only one row. Resolution is to use 'limit 1' with some 'order by' or some aggregate function - I'm not sure what you want to achieve